# JAVA not in path although JAVA_HOME set

Tags: java, linux, elasticsearch, environment-variables

I have set all the requirement variables in the /etc/profile but when launching elasticsearch, it is still not find Java. How i can set the environment variable. That's my /etc/profile

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
APPLICATIONS=$HOME/Applications
JAVA_HOME=$APPLICATIONS/jdk1.7.0_79
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

export APPLICATIONS
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

**Output of commands**

```
[root@87500e63467f Applications]# echo $PATH
/root/Applications/jdk1.7.0_79/bin:/root/Applications/jdk1.7.0_79/bin:/root/Applications/jdk1.7.0_79/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/bin:/root/bin
[root@87500e63467f Applications]# echo $JAVA_HOME
/root/Applications/jdk1.7.0_79
[root@87500e63467f Applications]# java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
error: "Read-only file system" setting key "vm.max_map_count"
Starting elasticsearch: which: no java in (/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin)
Could not find any executable java binary. Please install java in your PATH or set JAVA_HOME
                                                           [FAILED]
```

in the error, it says that ""Starting elasticsearch: which: no java in (/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin)"", it means really java isn't in that path, but how come when I echo $PATH, it shows that the java is in the path ?

Comment: Which version are you using of Linux?

Comment: what is the output of this > `ls -ltr /root/Applications/jdk1.7.0_79/bin` are you getting java??

Comment: i get this /root/Applications/jdk1.7.0_79/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/bin:/root/bin ls -ltr /root/Applications/jdk1.7.0_79/bin

Comment: I can't see how elasticsearch is started but the path shown there is very different from that you are setting. Try to source your profile before calling elastic search by ". /etc/profile".

Comment: when doing so, i get this error, error: "Read-only file system" setting key "vm.max_map_count"
Starting elasticsearch: which: no java in (/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin)
Could not find any executable java binary. Please install java in your PATH or set JAVA_HOME
                                                           [FAILED]

Comment: Which command is used to launch elasticsearch? Could it be changing to another user before launching? By the look of your output you start it as service and it would change to the elasticsearch user by default. It seems that it doesn't pick your profile. Try installing java in some other place other than root's home.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specifically for OpenBSD6.0, add

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk-1.8.0/
```

to your `.profile`.

This specific version of the jdk, and possibly the basic path itself is subject to change in subsequent and previous versions of OpenBSD, you have been warned.

Answer (score 36):

After reading the docs from ElasticSearch, I found that if you're running on Ubuntu or Debian, the package only ships with the OpenJDK because of licensing issues. To fix this Java path problem, I installed the following after installing ElasticSearch (as directed by the docs):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
java -version
```

Then upon running `sudo service elasticsearch start` everything worked and I had no more Java path issues.

Answer (score 14):

run the command

```
java -XshowSettings
```

search the entry `java.home = /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre`

export the java_home in your bash profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre
```

or in `/etc/profile` to expand to all users

Comment: This answer helped me... Thanks a lot bro

Answer (score 3):

To get it going - though not nice - you could setup a symbolic link to your java in /usr/bin (which is listed by elasticsearch to be seen):

```
ln -s /root/Applications/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java /usr/bin/java
```

Comment: How do you start elasticsearch (already asked by other commenters but I haven't seen an answer)? What it is the output if you do `which java`? What's the output of `/root/Applications/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java -version`? What the output of `ls -l /root/Applications/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java`?

Comment: i put all these in the answer part, all queries properly replies

Comment: @user1774937 What do you mean be "all queries properly replies"?

Comment: "Which Java" gives the proper output as well as when asking for the version

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the path you have provided for JAVA_HOME is correct.

And why not keep it simple:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/jdk
```

try to set Java home to /jdk1.7.0_79/bin and see if that helps.

Comment: but yet, my path is fine: /Applications/jdk1.7.0_79/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/bin:/root/bin and the path for java works, even java -version echoes the proper output as shown in the questiona above

Comment: @user1774937 java -version echoes the proper output as you have set it properly (until bin folder) to PATH. Try to set Java home to /jdk1.7.0_79/bin  and tell me what you get.

Comment: but there is nothing at /jdk1.7.0_79/bin, you want to tell me to move the jdk files there ?

Comment: @user1774937 How is that possible? What is inside your bin folder?

Comment: my jdk1.7.0_79 is found at /root/Applications/jdk1.7.0_79

Comment: oh MIS-understanding when i say jdk/bin what I really mean is     /root/Applications/jdk1.7.0_79/bin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93822/discussion-between-itguy-and-user1774937).

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the below path in `bashrc` and `profile` file under `/etc/` directory.

> export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/jdk
>
> export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 0):

I noticed one file in the output called /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch

this might do the trick, so I defined JAVA_HOME in this file like, and it works.

more u can get from [here](https://sys101.doloveyou.com/year/2015/articles/ElasticSearch_can_not_find_java_on_centos.html)

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue while installing Elasticsearch 5 on a debian machine. That's how I installed Java 9:

```
su -
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886
apt-get update
apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your particular situation, but working with ElasticSearch/Kibana/Logstash (ELK stack) the docs didn't work for me on Ubuntu 16.04. Putting content from this post together with several others, my solution was:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
 # checking my work given 9 won't work with OSSEC you can use
 # java -version
 sudo usermod -a -G ossec logstash
 sudo apt-get install logstash
 sudo systemctl daemon-reload
 sudo systemctl enable logstash.service
 sudo systemctl start logstash.service
```

The end result for me on ubuntu 16.04 was

```
sudo java -version
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

If you are working with wazuh, it is important to add the PPAs for their specific versions. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you need set JAVA_HOME in the /etc/default/elasticsearch,like
`cat /etc/default/elasticsearch
JAVA_HOME=/var/local/jdk1.8.0_151`

the next start 
`/etc/init.d/elasticsearch start`
ES running.
my OS ubuntu18.04.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "not installed" Java, check if your "elasticsearch" user has access to the defined by you JAVA_HOME directory and all parent directories. That was my problem..